# Allowing each user to only list some folders in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm setting up a new S3 bucket for my clients to upload into.  I would like to only allow each client to see only their own folder, so that the each client cannot tell who else I am working with.

I can set it up so that each client can't list or view objects *within* any other client's folder, but at the moment each of them can list all the folders in the bucket.

Ideally I would like that the top level of the bucket contains multiple folders e.g. `client-1-folder`, `client-2-folder` etc.  Then when someone logs in as `client-1`, they can only see `client-1-folder` and can't even see that the `client-2` folder exists (so they don't know that I'm working with client 2).

Is this possible via IAM permissions?

My current IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "id1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "id2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::client-bucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "client-1-folder/"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [
                        "/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible (each client will be able to list the buckets on top of getting the content of their bucket). But the best place to ask this type of questions is Server Fault - not Stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

This part of your policy:

```
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "client-1-folder/"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [
                        "/"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

is saying: "only if the prefix is empty, or it is `client-1-folder`.

Thus, it is allowing people to list the `root` of the bucket. If you remove the `""`, then they will only be allowed to list their own directory.

Also, rather than having to write a separate policy for each person, you can take advantage of **policy variables** like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This allows the same policy to be applied to all users without having to specify their username. However, it expects the folders to be named the same as their username.

See: [IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply John.  Do you know if there's a way to allow users to see the root of the bucket, but only have their folder listed within it?  I only ask as most of my users are business people and therefore will need to use the aws console to navigate from the root directory down to their folder (I'm guessing that the solution above would prevent them from doing that?)  Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: No, this is not possible. The permissions check the contents of the **request**. If the conditions are met, the user is allowed to run the command. Permissions do not limit the response of a command, except for checking what has been requested (which is why the above techniques work). The only way to do it would to require a _filter_ on the query, but that would just confuse users.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create different s3 buckets for different clients ? Create a dedicated bucket for every client. And then the user you create for every client, create the policy which allows the client to see only his/her s3 bucket.

Comment: Won't the users still be able to see the names of the other buckets though?  I need them to access their bucket through AWS console, so to make that work I think that they need the 's3:ListAllMyBuckets' action?